# I keep getting 'must have to be writable!' error when downloading

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I keep getting this error:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/download-manager/cache/ must have to be writable!
```

when I try to download something off my WordPress website. It is on AWS and Bitnami Ubuntu. I do have shell access and stuck with it. If someone can, please, help me out with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just running below command it worked

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/your_plugin_directory 
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/your_plugin_directory
```

Taken from here: http://wiki.bitnami.com/BitNami_Cloud_Hosting/Servers/Access_your_machine#Files_writable_by_the_web_server